# Why rectangles don't appear the same (or at all) when style is moved to CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

Pink/middle rectangle is visible.  Top and bottom are not, have had their style moved to a class in external CSS.  Inspecting element shows a 1x1 image at top/rightmost side? of the svg area.  I am not sure why having the style attributes in the external CSS would cause the rectangles not to render as expected.  Please explain.

[image: Shows middle rectangle]

[image: Shows invisible rectangle]

[image]

```css
.countLegend p {
  margin: 0em;
  line-height: 1;
}

.legendTotal {
  width:1.3em;
  height:0.8em;
  fill: rgb(135, 206, 250);
}

.legendRejected {
  width:1.3em;
  height:0.8em;
  fill: rgb(197, 132, 240);
}

.legendInternalRejected {
  width:1.3em;
  height:0.8em;
  fill: rgb(220, 20, 60);
}

.legendKey {
  height: 1em;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="countLegend">
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey">
            <rect y="0.2em" x="0.5em" class="legendTotal"></rect>
        </svg>
        Count
        <span id="spnTotalTrans" class="legendValue">10,250</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey">
            <rect y="0.2em" x="0.5em" width="1.3em" height="0.8em" style="fill: rgb(197, 132, 240);"></rect>
        </svg>
        Rejections Total
        <span id="spnRejectedTrans" class="legendValue">86,335</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey">
            <rect y="0.2em" x="0.5em"></rect>
        </svg>
        Rejections Internal
        <span id="spnIntRejectedTrans" class="legendValue">86,335</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: If the CSS is no longer applied when you move it to an external stylesheet, the reason is going to be because you are not calling that external stylesheet properly, *or* your selectors are competing with each other.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle That's a terrible suggestion. `!important` is a hack and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle NO!...important is the nuclear option and should be avoided.

Comment: `!important` is a useful debugging tool to determine if the problem is one of specificity.

Comment: I mean't for testing purposes @TylerH, its useful to see if CSS selectors are conflicting/arguing.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle That's a little better, though I still think it would be better to use a non-hack, like `border: 1px solid black;` or `background: red;`, because even the `!important` hack can be unreliable.

Comment: They may not be conflicting over those specific attributes, @TylerH

Comment: For example, if I am using a stylesheet where two or more selectors are competing with each other over say.. font-size, and no matter what I do to a CSS selector, the font-size won't change, I would use !important to quickly eliminate all other font-size specifications for that element/declarations that that element inherits - if only to check that my sheet is working as it should. @TylerH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using SVG elements, which require `height` and `width` *attributes*, not CSS *properties*. The difference is that, as attributes of the SVG element, they *cannot* be moved to CSS.

According to the [SVG Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement), for both `height` and `width` attributes:

> A value of 0 disables rendering of the element.

As you can see if you edit the attributes back into the SVG element, the `fill` property [is still being applied](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/j0ovp6n5/), so the CSS is actually not being ignored.

```css
.countLegend p {
  margin: 0em;
  line-height: 1;
}

.legendTotal {
  fill: rgb(135, 206, 250);
}

.legendRejected {
  width:1.3em;
  height:0.8em;
  fill: rgb(197, 132, 240);
}

.legendInternalRejected {
  width:1.3em;
  height:0.8em;
  fill: rgb(220, 20, 60);
}

.legendKey {
  height: 1em;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="countLegend">
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey">
            <rect y="0.2em" x="0.5em" height="0.8em" width="1.3em" class="legendTotal"></rect>
        </svg>
        Count
        <span id="spnTotalTrans" class="legendValue">10,250</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey">
            <rect y="0.2em" x="0.5em" width="1.3em" height="0.8em" style="fill: rgb(197, 132, 240);"></rect>
        </svg>
        Rejections Total
        <span id="spnRejectedTrans" class="legendValue">86,335</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <svg class="legendKey">
            <rect y="0.2em" x="0.5em"></rect>
        </svg>
        Rejections Internal
        <span id="spnIntRejectedTrans" class="legendValue">86,335</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SVG (unlike HTML) width and height (and x and y) of `<rect>` elements are [attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) rather than [CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html). As such they cannot be set in CSS and must be set in the SVG document as markup.

In fact most sizing/positioning in SVG is via attributes rather than CSS. There are plans to change this in the upcoming SVG 2 specification but that specification is both unfinished and not yet implemented.